# Converting Nested Objects into Mongoose compatible format

Tags: json, mongoose, redis, mern

I am trying to use redis for caching data for my application. I'm storing data in redis like:

```
const result = await exec.apply(this,arguments);
client.set(key,JSON.stringify(result));
```

and then using cached data for application like:

```
const cachedValue = await client.get(key);
if(cachedValue){

   const doc = JSON.parse(cachedValue);
   return Array.isArray(doc) ? doc.map(d => new this.model(d)) : new this.model(doc)
}
```

Turning cached data into mongoose document model by using `new this.model`. It is working fine for a single object and array of objects but it fails for nested objects such as

```
{
        "attendance": {
            "classesHeld": 0,
            "classesTaken": 0,
            "classesLeft": 0,
            "date": {
                "$date": "2018-10-30T14:37:21.596Z"
            }
        },
        "GPA": 0,
        "date": {
            "$date": "2018-10-30T14:37:21.596Z"
        },
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5bd86ca19ffc0feb81434ac3"
        },
        "name": "OOC & Programming",
        "code": "SE-201",
        "ch": 4,
        "teacher": "ada",
        "semester": "Second"
}
```

What could be the possible solution for this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Where does it fail?

Comment: @Geert-Jan When i try to convert nested objects into Mongoose document